# How to get the duplicates from the lists based on name

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe, duplicates

I am accessing some files from the server and printing the results but how can I get the duplicates based on the name from the printed results.

```
from datetime import datetime
class EsriApiMaps:

    def __init__(self, portal, item_type, query):
        self.item_type = item_type
        self.query_ = query
        self.portal = portal

    def query_maps(self):
        api_query_result = self.portal.content.search(query=self.query_, item_type=self.item_type)
        l = [] # we will store all the services e,g url,id,owner etc


        for l in api_query_result:
            l_created_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(round(l.created / 1000))
            l_modified_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(round(l.modified / 1000))
            df = ("Name: " + l.title + "ID: " + l.id + ", Owner: " + l.owner + ", Created: " + str(l_created_time) + ", Modified: " + str(l_modified_time))
            print(df)
```

I have tried this to get the below results,

```
Name: KL, ID: af57c454, Owner: Scripter, Created: 2019-10-08 12:57:45, Modified: 2019-10-08 12:57:45
Name: KL, ID: dfsjd5s4, Owner: d011, Created: 2020-10-27 21:02:54, Modified: 2020-10-27 21:02:54
Name: TEAM, ID: b8djx8, Owner: j277, Created: 2019-10-08 12:52:54, Modified: 2019-10-08 12:52:54
Name: ALL, ID: b896sfd, Owner: rp10, Created: 2019-10-11 14:51:38, Modified: 2019-10-11 14:51:38
Name: MD, ID: dhx865, Owner: ws07, Created: 2019-10-08 15:17:59, Modified: 2019-10-08 15:17:59
Name: AJKL, ID: dhsa88, Owner: fsdd, Created: 2020-07-23 16:04:20, Modified: 2020-07-23 16:04:20
Name: MD, ID: sd5425, Owner: fsdd, Created: 2021-02-02 11:43:15, Modified: 2021-02-02 11:43:15
Name: MD, ID: vcxb65, Owner: dsff1, Created: 2020-06-17 10:56:36, Modified: 2020-06-17 10:56:36
```

I have tried using,

```
names = df.Name.value_counts()
names[names>1]
```

But I am getting this error **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Name'**

How can I get the duplicates based on its name ?

The expected result is

```
Name: KL, ID: af57c454, Owner: Scripter, Created: 2019-10-08 12:57:45, Modified: 2019-10-08 12:57:45
Name: KL, ID: dfsjd5s4, Owner: d011, Created: 2020-10-27 21:02:54, Modified: 2020-10-27 21:02:54
Name: MD, ID: sd5425, Owner: fsdd, Created: 2021-02-02 11:43:15, Modified: 2021-02-02 11:43:15
Name: MD, ID: vcxb65, Owner: dsff1, Created: 2020-06-17 10:56:36, Modified: 2020-06-17 10:56:36
Name: MD, ID: dhx865, Owner: ws07, Created: 2019-10-08 15:17:59, Modified: 2019-10-08 15:17:59
```

Comment: df it's a string, not a dataframe, you should create a dataframe with the results of the API query and then you could use de dataframe methods.

Comment: @Xavi, I am using this l = [] to get the url from the API query and using the url I get the created and modified time, If I convert it to a dataframe how Can I do that ?? I have tried to convert the df into dataframe but I get an error  **ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df it's a string, not a dataframe, you should create a dataframe with the results of the API query and then you could use de dataframe methods.

You can create a list with the results and then initialize the dataframe witht it.

```py
def query_maps(self):
        api_query_result = self.portal.content.search(query=self.query_, item_type=self.item_type)
        data = []

        for l in api_query_result:
            l_created_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(round(l.created / 1000))
            l_modified_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(round(l.modified / 1000))
            data.append({"Name": l.title, "ID": l.id, "Owner": l.owner, "Created": str(l_created_time), "Modified": str(l_modified_time)})
        df = pd.Dataframe(data)
```